# How to pass an object to a Mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js

I've got a custom Node server and to pass it as an object to some tests. This is my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Add the grunt-mocha-test tasks.
grunt.loadTasks('node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/tasks');

grunt.initConfig({
    // Configure a mochaTest task
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    mochaTest: {
        test: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec',
                globals : 'MyServer'

            },
            src: ['./server/test/custom/*.js']
        }
    }
});
```

How do I use the variable I created in my Gruntfile in my tests? Is there another way to pass stuff to my tests?

Answer (score 1):

From the mocha docs:

> --globals
>
> Accepts a comma-delimited list of accepted global variable names. For example, suppose your app deliberately exposes a global named app and YUI, you may want to add --globals app,YUI. It also accepts wildcards. You could do --globals '*bar' and it would match foobar, barbar, etc. You can also simply pass in '*' to ignore all globals.

In short, the globals option is used to tell mocha to ignore certain globals, not to expose those variables in your test.

If you want to test a module with mocha, you should just `require` it in your tests (or a test helper).

A framework like [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) will wrap an HTTPServer and allow you test endpoints quite nicely. I've created a short [example](https://github.com/NickTomlin/http-supertest-example) that shows how you can use supertest and mocha to test a simple HTTPServer application. Relevant code below:

```
// index.js
var http = require('http');

module.exports = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});
```

```
// server-test.js
var server = require('./index.js');
var supertest = require('supertest');
var app = supertest(app);

describe('server', function () {
  it('responds with a welcoming message', function (done) {
    app.get('/')
      .expect(200, /Hello World/, done);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @nick ! Well what I'm trying to do is test my custom server. I used to `require` it in each of my test files but that ended up booting/stopping the server with each test file....I'm trying to pass them a server object t avoid the booting/stopping

Comment: @BenZifkin that's probably because you are starting your server when the file is required. I'd recommend _not_ doing that, and instead exposing a method that starts your server. This will make it much easier to test and reuse. If you really must do that, just require your server once, in a helper file, and then hit it in your individual tests.

Comment: Awesome! So, @nick I write a method to start the server. expose it, then start it in my first test file right? Then, how would I make sure that my subsequent test were using the same server?

Comment: If you are going to manually start your application, do it in a `before` block in a a test helper file (you can use a mocha `after` block to shut it down). I'm not sure what you mean by using the same server. As long as you know your app hasn't restarted it should be the same.

Comment: I've seen similar solution involving a test helper file, but as far as I can tell that works for HTML, I'm trying to test REST api on various models...Not sure how to structure a test helper file

Comment: Sorry I'm not trying to get you to walk me through it or anything...it's just I really don't know where to go with this

Comment: A helper is just a javascript file that is included in your test suite, so there's no limitations.  Here's an [example](https://github.com/NickTomlin/flux-talk/blob/master/test/server/support/test-helper.js#L9). I register a global `request` object (I'm using supertest) and then use it in my [tests](https://github.com/NickTomlin/flux-talk/blob/master/test/server/api.test.js#L15) to make requests to my application. I use mocha's options to [include](https://github.com/NickTomlin/flux-talk/blob/master/test/mocha.opts) the test helper in my test suite.